Get PDF metadata from a blob
I have a blob in Flutter code that contains a PDF.
I would like to get two items from this blob: the file name and its title.
I saw several tips on how to get it from a physical file already saved on the device but I want to get it from the blob before saving.
import 'dart:html' as html;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

Future salvaStringEmPDF(String id) async {
  var url = "https://api.XXXXXX.com.br/XX/documentos/" +
      id +
      "/pdf?incluir_fonte_pdf=true";

  var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url), headers: {
    "Accept": "application/pdf",
    "Authorization": "Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  });

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    List<int> bytes = response.bodyBytes;

    final blob = html.Blob([bytes], 'application/pdf'); <--- I want to get the PDF properties from this object

    final url = html.Url.createObjectUrlFromBlob(blob);

    (...more code...)
  } else {
    print("Api deu ERROR");
  }
}

I tried to get the object's properties from the URL but it doesn't have these properties.

Thanks. I'll try something with your suggestion.
